# Finding an expression for the number of trees in a full graph with $n$ nodes and $k$ edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Define a full graph to be a graph in which all pairs of nodes are joined by exactly $k$ edges (so when $k = 1$, we have a complete graph). Also, let $f(k, n)$ denote the number of trees in a full graph on $n$ nodes and $k$ edges. How can I find a closed-form expression for $f(k, n)$?

I'm pretty sure that $f(1, n) = {n(n - 1)/2 \choose n - 1}$ since a complete graph has $n(n - 1)/2$ vertices and we can choose any $n - 1$ of them to form a tree. But I'm not entirely sure. I think I should try to come up with a recurrence and try to solve the recurrence, but I've been having trouble doing so.

Could someone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Just to be sure: you mean trees that include all $n$ vertices?

Comment: A complete graph on $n$ vertices has $n(n-1)/2$ **edges** not vertices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f(1,n)$, you cannot choose *any* $n-1$ edges to form a tree; you need to make sure you avoid creating cycles. By Cayley's formula, $f(1,n)=n^{n-2}$.

As you said in the comments, you can quickly derive $f(k,n)$ from $f(1,n)$ by using combinatorics, but you should not use $k!$. To choose a tree on the full graph, you first choose a tree in $f(1,n)$ ways, and then you choose which of the $k$ edges you use for each edge. There are $n-1$ edges to choose, and $k$ choices for each edge, so how many ways are there to make all the choices?

Comment: Would we just have $f(k, n) = k \cdot f(1, n) = k \cdot n^{n - 1}$? And just to clarify, this is the number of trees that includes all $n$ vertices, right? (so a spanning tree)

Comment: No, you need to have an exponent on $k$, since a $k$-way choice is being made $n-1$ times. For example, with $k=2$, there are $n-1$ doubled edges, and you are selecting one out of each pair. Also, yes, I am assuming spanning trees... I do not know the answer if you just mean trees in general.

Comment: I understand now. It should be $f(k, n) = k^{n - 1} n^{n - 2}$.

Comment: @DarthVader55 Exactly!

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the question that they only want to count **spanning** trees, so shouldn't the answer be $$\sum_{m=1}^n\binom nmk^{m-1}m^{m-2}\ ?$$